# How to split an image dataset in X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a dataset like the following the structure:

```
Dataset/
   |
   |
   -----Pothole/
   |         |
   |         ------ umm001.jpg
   |         |
   |         ------ abd.jpg
   |         |
   |         ------ 
   |         |
   |
   |
   ----Road/
         |
         ------road005.jpg
         |
         ------ummm.jpg
         |
         ------
         |
```

I want to split this dataset into `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test`.

such that:

```
### data: shuffled and split between train and test
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Or,

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.20)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build `X` and `y` arrays using the `os` module:

```
import os

X = []
y = []
base_dir = '<full path to dataset folder>/'
for f in sorted(os.listdir(base_dir)):
    if os.path.isdir(base_dir+f):
        print(f"{f} is a target class")
        for i in sorted(os.listdir(base_dir+f)):
            print(f"{i} is an input image path")
            X.append(base_dir+f+'/'+i)
            y.append(f)
print(X)
print(y)
```

Then you can use `train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.20)` to get what you need, but bear in mind that you will have to open the images using other library like `pillow` or `scikit-image` or a similar one.

If you are planning to use `pytorch` to train a neural network, you can use their `ImageFolder` [class](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#afterword-torchvision) to create your dataset.